# Closing concurrent server socket (TCP)

Tags: c, sockets, server, client

I'm making a concurrent server/client program in C using threads. Whenever a client connects, I create a new thread to handle it.

My problem is: I want to be able to close the server, from the client. With the command '..' for example. When I type '..' in the client, I want the server to close immediately.

I thought about having a global variable, that indicates wether the server should close or not. The problem is: When the thread is created to handle the client, the main thread goes back to accept(), and it cannot check that variable. So, it will only close when a new client connects.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not quite sure on this, but my starting point would be find out whether `shutdown` on the socket interrupts an ongoing `accept` call.

Comment: When I use shutdown(), accept() returns -1, and says "Invalid arguments"... What to do with this information? Should I just return 0, if accept() returns -1? @mrksngl

Comment: What I mean is: when any of your client thread calls shutdown on the socket, the main thread a) either was just inside of `accept` and it returns with `EINVAL` or b) it will call `accept` again in a moment, also resulting in `EINVAL`. So after you got EINVAL from accept, you can check your stop condition.

Comment: Can you not just call your OS 'Terminate Process', 'exit', whatever from your client thread?  Your OS, if non-trivial, (eg linux, Windows), will then happily splat all the other threads etc.

Comment: So I read about `shutdown`, revising my statements above: you cannot call `shutdown` on non-connected sockets. That means: you can, but it will fail (`ENOTCONN`) as it is only meant for connected sockets. Closing the socket instead is a bad idea as it will lead to a race condition. Please consider the other comments and answers here.

Comment: Thanks for the help, guys! I solved my issue using a SIGINT signal, that I send from a thread to the main thread, telling it to close the server.

Comment: threads take a long time to create.  Much better to have created a 'thread pool' and pass each new client to a 'idle' thread

Answer (score 0):

Use `select()` or `(e)poll()` or equivalent to wait for a client to connect BEFORE you then call `accept()` to accept the connection.  Those kind of functions allow you to specify a timeout, that will allow you to stop waiting periodically to check for other conditions, like a shutdown request.  On some platforms, you can even have these functions wait on not only the listening socket but also a separate pipe that you create privately for yourself, and when you want to "wake up" your waiting loop to do something, simply write a byte into that pipe, and when the loop detects that byte arriving then it can act accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I had no idea about the existance of those calls. I solved my issue using signals, but I'll try to implement this solution too.